# Unknown behaviour of Object.values() in Arrow Function

Tags: javascript, html, arrow-functions

I'm making a random password generator in Vannila JS , I'm facing a unknown problem in following code :

```js
function generatePassword(lower, upper, number, symbol, length) {
  let generatedPassword = "";
  const typesCount = lower + upper + number + symbol;
  const typesArr = [{ lower }, { upper }, { number }, { symbol }].filter(
    (item) => Object.values(item)[0]
  );

  // Doesn't have a selected type
  if (typesCount === 0) {
    return "";
  }

  // create a loop
  for (let i = 0; i < length; i += typesCount) {
    typesArr.forEach((type) => {
      const funcName = Object.keys(type)[0];
      generatedPassword += randomFunc[funcName]();
    });
  }

  const finalPassword = generatedPassword.slice(0, length);

  return finalPassword;
}
```

In this block of code specifically the **Object.values(item)[0]** doesn't work if I enclose the statement in Curly Braces {} :

```
const typesArr = [{ lower }, { upper }, { number }, { symbol }].filter(
    (item) => Object.values(item)[0]
  );
```

I don't understand why this is happening , I tried searching docs but no avail , Thanks !

Comment: What error are you getting now without curly braces?

Comment: I checked the console but I doesn't seem to give error when I enclose it in curly braces , but the code doesn't work either...
But If the curly braces are removed code works just fine

Comment: Do you mean it doesn't work if you write `const typesArr = [{ lower }, { upper }, { number }, { symbol }].filter(
    (item) =>  { Object.values(item)[0] }
  );`

Comment: Exactly , It doesn't work this way & doesn't even show any errors

Comment: `.filter(
    (item) => Object.values(item)[0]
  );` what are you trying so in this code. Did you mean to use `.map()` method, because filter is used to filter an array and then return that value not to return a specific value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order for Filter function to correctly work, it needs to return. a truthy of falsy value.

When you write it like

```
const typesArr = [{ lower }, { upper }, { number }, { symbol }].filter(
    (item) => Object.values(item)[0]
  );
```

The result is implicitly return ie. Object.values(item)[0] is a returned value

However if you write it like

```
const typesArr = [{ lower }, { upper }, { number }, { symbol }].filter(
    (item) => { Object.values(item)[0] }
  );
```

You haven't returned any value from the filter function, you would need to add a return statement for it like

```
const typesArr = [{ lower }, { upper }, { number }, { symbol }].filter(
    (item) => { return Object.values(item)[0]; }
);
```

Comment: if you can answer this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61204297/best-way-to-pass-parameters-in-onclick-handler please