# Most efficient way to pass parameters in onClick handler

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am using inline arrow function to change the `onClick` handlers of some divs in my React component, but I know it is not a good way in terms of performance.

Objectively, what is the most efficient way of setting `onClick` handlers that require arguments? This is what I have tried:

**1. Inline arrow function**

```
changeRoute (routeName) {
  console.log(routeName)
}
render() {
  return (
    <>
      <div onClick={() => this.changeRoute("page1")}>1</div>
      <div onClick={() => this.changeRoute("page2")}>2</div>
    </>
  )
}
```

**2. If I use constructor binding then how can I pass props?**

```
constructor() {
  super(props)
  this.changeRoute = this.changeRoute.bind(this)
}
changeRoute (routeName) {
  console.log(routeName)
}
render() {
  return (
    <>
      <div onClick={this.changeRoute}>1</div>
      <div onClick={this.changeRoute}>2</div>
    </>
  )
}
```

**3. If I remove the arrow function then the function being called on the render itself**

```
changeRoute (routeName) {
  console.log(routeName)
}
render() {
  return (
    <>
      <div onClick={this.changeRoute("page1")}>1</div>
      <div onClick={this.changeRoute("page2")}>2</div>
    </>
  )
}
```

**4. If I use inline binding then it is also not best with performance**

```
changeRoute (routeName) {
  console.log(routeName)
}
render() {
  return (
    <>
      <div onClick={this.changeRoute.bind(this, "page1")}>1</div>
      <div onClick={this.changeRoute.bind(this, "page2")}>2</div>
    </>
  )
}
```

Then how can I proceed with the best way passing parameters?

Comment: It's probably worth noting that the *reason* why using inline arrow functions here "is not [a] good way in terms of performance" isn't because arrow functions would somehow be intrinsically slow to run (they're not, and in any case the cost of a function call is totally negligible for something as rarely executed as a click handler) but because React will create new instances of the functions every time the component is re-rendered. Inline binding has the exact same issue. And it's usually fine anyway, unless the component gets re-rendered *very* frequently.

Comment: @IlmariKaronen In most of the cases component re-renders frequently because the components have input field and typing & setting the e.target.value in state result in frequent render.

Answer (score 6):

You can use arrow function to define your `changeRoute` handler.

This is known as `Class field syntax`. More on it [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/handling-events.html) in official react docs.

```
constructor() {
  super(props)
}

changeRoute = (parameter) => (event) => {
    // business logic for route change.
}
```

Then you can use this function directly like so:

```
render() {
  return (
    <>
      <div onClick={changeRoute(params1)}>1</div>
      <div onClick={changeRoute(params2)}>2</div>
    </>
  )
}
```

You do not have to worry about the binding. 
Arrow functions inherit their parent's `this`.

Comment: @DarkKnight Your last comment was `executing on the go`. My answer is in response to that.

I am trying to tell you that your click handler will not `execute on the go` if you define the handler like I have posted.

Comment: Pls check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29810914/react-js-onclick-cant-pass-value-to-method#comment78741749_45448802)

Comment: @DarkKnight Please read this https://reactjs.org/docs/handling-events.html
Class field syntax is one of the recommended methods by official react docs.

Comment: Is this the most efficient way of passing an argument? here function is called every time on re render. same as bind. How is it more efficient?

Comment: Performance wise it is same as using bind. `public class fields syntax` is just syntactic sugar. You can read more on that here https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-plugin-proposal-class-properties.

Comment: this approach is not correct, function gets called while rendering

Answer (score 4):

You can add a data to your div:

```
<div data-id={1} onClick={this.changeRoute}>1</div>
```

Then you can retrieve that data in your onClick handler:

```
onClick = (event) => {
  const id = event.currentTarget.dataset.id;
}
```

Comment: Ha ha ha... Can be done. But the react himself does not have work around?

Answer (score 2):

**#1** is fine.

**#2** is also 'fine', but you need to pass props, then the **render** function will look exactly like **#1**. You will be calling the `bind`'d function, because you replaced it in the constructor.

**#3** is just wrong, as the function gets called during render.

And regarding #4, from react [docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/handling-events.html)

> We generally recommend binding in the constructor or using the class
>   fields syntax, to avoid this sort of performance problem.

This causes a performance penalty when your function is used in its child components and will cause the child components to re-render (its not in your case). So you shouldn't do **#4**.

Answer (score 1):

The best way currently is to wrap your event handler in `useCallback` hook as it will prevent your handler function from being created each time render is called.

```js
import React, { useCallback } from 'react'

const MyComponent = ({ changeRoute }) => {
  const eventHandler = useCallback(() => {
    changeRoute('page1')
  }, [changeRoute])

  return (
    <div onClick={eventHandler}>1</div>
  )
}
```

For more info check - [useCallback docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usecallback)

Comment: The OP would appear to be using a class component, where you can't use hooks.

Comment: I hope my answer will help him to understand the better way

Answer (score 0):

Below is another way to read parameter. Here you don't need to create another function inside the arrow function to pass parameter.

```
const Simple = () => {
    
    const handleClick = (e) => {
      e.preventDefault()
      let id = e.target.getAttribute('data-id')
      console.log(id) // prints hello
      console.log('This is handle click')
    }
    
    return (
      <>
        <a onClick={handleClick} data-id='hello'>Click here</a>
      </>
    )
    
    }
```